# XWPFRun.setText() doesn't seem to respect line breaks or tabs?

Tags: java, ms-office, apache-poi, doc

Here is the sample code, the "\t" not work for this setText method?:

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFParagraph tp = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun tRun = tp.createRun();
tRun.setText("a");
tRun.setText("\t"); // not work
tRun.setText("b");

FileOutputStream outStream = null;
try {
    outStream = new FileOutputStream("testTabWithPOI.doc");
    document.write(outStream);
    outStream.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That isn't how you add tabs or newlines into a run. The way that Microsoft Words generates the files is to add special break style elements, and therefore that's what you need to do in Apache POI too, since that's how the format works.

You can see an example of adding tags in [testAddTabsAndLineBreaks() of TestXWPFRun](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/TestXWPFRun.java). Your code needs to be:

```
XWPFRun tRun = tp.createRun();
tRun.setText("a");
tRun.addTab();
tRun.setText("b");
```

(You'll need to be using a new copy of Apache POI too for `addTab()` support)